# How to make jquery autocomplete works from usercontrol using webservice

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have jQuery to pull the autocomplete record as I type in the textbox, this data is being fetched using webservice. Now, everything works fine while using in Default.aspx page, but when I use this process from UserControl.ascx and call it in the default.aspx page then it doesn't return the autocomplete data (result).
WebService.asmx code:
 [WebMethod]

```
public List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYCONNECTION"].ConnectionString;
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT SSName from SSRecord where SSName LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", username);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result.Add(dr["SSName "].ToString());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl.ascx code:

```
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();               
        });
        function SearchText() {
            $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "WebService.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }); 
        }
    </script>

<label for="tbAuto">Enter UserName: </label>   
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" class="autosuggest"></asp:TextBox>
```

Default.aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="UserControl" %>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <uc1: UserControl  runat="server" ID="UserControl"/> 
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar post on the below link. Therefore, after some modification mentioned in the link I am able to sort this out.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-jQuery-Autocomplete-using-Web-Service-in-ASP.Net.aspx